# SCSS nesting nth-of-type

Tags: css, sass, nested

Using SCSS and have a nested element which I am trying to nest an `nth-of-type()` rule into but it hasn't worked anyway I type it. I want every odd `el_header` element to be white text and every even one to be black.

```
.el {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;

  &_header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    background: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 500px;
    text-align: center;

    &nth-of-type(odd) {
      color: black;
    }
    &nth-of-type(even) {
      color: white;
    }

  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p3gro32d/)

Comment: Add ":" after your &.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 9):

You just forgot the `:` after `&`.

Use

```
&:nth-of-type(odd){...}

&:nth-of-type(even){...}
```

and it will work.
See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3gro32d/1/)

Comment: It works in the fiddle but not in my actual code, but the actual code is too long to make people on SO look through.

Comment: @Shniper try `.el_header` as selector. See https://jsfiddle.net/p3gro32d/4/